# I completely cannot include boost headers

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015

I needed a boost's "filesystem" so I downloaded and successfully build the whole boost. Its directory is `C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_60_0\boost`

Then I created a vs project and specified include directories, additional include directories and library directories. A couple of ways. Tried to add it to the system path, created a system variable bouth with setx an manually.

```
C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_60_0; $(BOOST_ROOT); 
"evaluetes to" C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_60_0
```

But I still can't include and use anything.

```
#include <boost\filesystem> // error
#include "boost//filesystem.hpp" //error
#include <boost\filesystem.hpp> //error
#include "C://Program Files//Boost//boost_1_60_0//boost" //error

// those are working but still useless due to includes in the "filesystem.hpp"
#include "C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_60_0\boost\filesystem.hpp"
#include <C:\Program Files/Boost//boost_1_60_0\boost\filesystem.hpp>


#include <filesystem> // does not give an error, but following 
using namespace boost::filesystem; //still does
```

By the way, I worked with boost in this same ide a couple of weeks ago. And things were ok, not sure how I got it working back then though.

What could possibly be wrong? I'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already built the library. You need to right-click on your Visual Studio project and click `Properties`.

As you can see on those pictures, specify the **Additional Include Directories** to `C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_60_0` and **Additional Library Directories** to `C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_60_0\stage\lib`:

[image]

[image]

Then click `OK`

To include the boost filesystem write:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

Let me know if you're still having problems after this.

Comment: I did buit it and my include/library paths was correct. But it did not work till I switched project to win32, but now I can't use some other library, and need to build boost for x64.